# Animation in SvelteKit not working when applied through #each loop

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using this animation to make words appear on the screen in a sequence. Below this would work and no issues:

```js
<h1 class="lines">&nbsp;
        {#if animate}
        <span
                in:fly={{
              delay: 300,
              duration: 300,
              easing: backOut,
              y: 100,
          }}
        >
            One
        </span>
            <span
                    in:fly={{
              delay: 600,
              duration: 300,
              easing: backOut,
              y: 100,
          }}
            >
            Two
        </span>
            <span
                    in:fly={{
              delay: 900,
              duration: 300,
              easing: backOut,
              y: 100,
          }}
            >
            Three
        </span>
        {/if}
    </h1>
```

However, I prefer to use `#each` loop. I was able to get it working with some magic only, which seems totally wrong. Also, lint is not happy.
What would be the correct way without `#await tick` and `:then`? I'm using simple string Array no fetch involved at all, so not sure why animation works with tick() and await, but not without.

```js
<h1 class="lines">&nbsp;
        {#if animate}
            {#each words as word, i}
                {#await tick()}
                {:then}
                <span
                        in:fly={{
                          delay: 300 * i,
                          duration: 300,
                          easing: backOut,
                          y: 100,
                  }}
                >
                    {word}
                </span>
                {/await}
            {/each}
        {/if}
    </h1>
```

I tried to achieve above by following the following post and it is straight forward, however it is for **Svelte** and not **SvelteKit**. https://joyofcode.xyz/animation-with-svelte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Svelte 4 [transitions are local by default](https://svelte.dev/docs/v4-migration-guide#transitions-are-local-by-default)

So either adding the `|global` flag to the transition or moving the `#if` block inside the `#each` will make it work.

Adding `display: inline-block` or `inline-flex` will make the `y` value of the transition have an effect on the `span` elements

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/3999696c0e744454a22a69be8a53c063?version=4.0.5)

```
<script>
    import {fly} from 'svelte/transition'
    import {backOut} from 'svelte/easing'
    const words = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
    let animate = false
</script>

<button on:click={() => animate = !animate}>
    toggle
</button>

<h1 class="lines">
    {#each words as word, i}              
        {#if animate}
            <span
                in:fly={{
                    delay: 300 * i,
                    duration: 300,
                    easing: backOut,
                    y: 100,
                }}
                >
                {word}
            </span>                
        {/if}
    {/each}
</h1>

<h1 class="lines">
    {#if animate}
        {#each words as word, i}              
            <span
                in:fly|global={{
                    delay: 300 * i,
                    duration: 300,
                    easing: backOut,
                    y: 100,
                }}
                >
                {word}
            </span>                
        {/each}
    {/if}
</h1>

<style>
    span {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
```